# How to make .counts return 2 counts instead of 1

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this line of code in my Django templates that returns counts of comments like 1, 2, 3...

`<li class="list-inline-item">comms: {{ article.comments.count }}</li>`

How do I make it return counts in twos for every comment? like 2, 4, 6...

I can provide further details if need be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple solutions for this:

1. Add a property on your `Article` model which will do the multiplication for you

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def comments_count_multiplied(self):
        return 2 * self.comments.count()
```

Now you can use this in your template:

```html
<li class="list-inline-item">comms: {{ article.comments_count_multiplied }}</li>
```

2. Register a custom [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters) and use it in your template:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def multiply_with_two(value):
    return 2 * value
```

And in your template:

```html
<li class="list-inline-item">comms: {{ article.comments.count|multiply_with_two }}</li>
```